# page, driven by selenium, does not finish loading and cannot be introspected

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to navigate a page. When I go to it manually, it loads fine. When I have java-selenium drive, however, the page never finishes loaded and so cannot be introspected.

This code was working until recently. Then the target page got flaky somehow and now....

See: https://inmatepublicview.maderacounty.com/

```
Chromedriver driver() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    String width = "1920", height = "1080";
    options.addArguments(U.string("window-size=",width,",",height));
    if (!U.isLocal()) {
        options.addArguments("--headless");
    }
    options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.addArguments("--bwsi");
    options.addArguments("--log-level=3");
    options.addArguments("--no-default-browser-check");
    options.addArguments("--user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0\"");
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] { "enable-automation" });
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}

void mainThing() {
    ChromeDriver driver = null;

    try {
        driver = DJU.driver();
   driver.navigate().to("https://inmatepublicview.maderacounty.com/");
        wait(10);

        WebElement lastNameField = driver.findElementById("txtLname");
        WebElement button = driver.findElementById("btnSearch");
        lastNameField.sendKeys(initial);
        button.click();

... just hangs here, forever, with the spin indicator on the page going...
```

I can think of work-arounds. I could get the page source, parse out the link values myself and so on and so forth. But that is just ducking the problem.

Any ideas?

I run this code on a Mac 10.15.4 and also on Ubuntu 18.04.3.

Comment: Try adding page loading strategy eager and so forth.

Comment: Why do you set Firefox options for ChromeDriver here: options.addArguments("--user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0\"");

Comment: I am setting these Firefox options to get around the checking of some websites that do not like being scraped.